# php - Unexpected behavior when assigning a variable with new

Tags: php, class, variable-assignment

I am a bit confused with the following code example. I would guess that the second assignment `$ins = new A();` would override the previous `$ins` reference.

I also don't understand the `#1`, `#2`, neither the `(1),(1)` in the `var_dump` output, I would expect at least `(0),(0)`.

Thanks in advance

```
class A{

    public $var = 2;

}

$ins = new A();

$aux = &$ins;

$ins->var = 3;

var_dump($aux);
echo '<br>';

$ins = new A();

$ins->var = 5;

var_dump($aux);
```

prints

```
object(A)#1 (1) { ["var"]=> int(3) }
object(A)#2 (1) { ["var"]=> int(5) }
```

Comment: the 1's represent how many values it sees as a count of values in the array.

Comment: Thanks, I found an answer there
http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.references.php#95522

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

> A PHP reference is an alias, which allows two different variables to
>   write to the same value. As of PHP 5, an object variable doesn't
>   contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object
>   identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.
>   When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another
>   variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of
>   the identifier, which points to the same object.